# Teradata Studio Express "Filter History View" is not working

Tags: teradata

I am using Teradata Studio Express 17.10.  I love the history view and adding notes to easily find queries I have run before.

I am trying to filter the history "NOTEs" and it is not working out for me.

Here is a sample of my history:

[history view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sASAf.jpg)

Here's the filter pane view:

[filter pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY59w.jpg)

And here's my blank/empty results set:

[no results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMrq0.jpg)

Appreciate any ideas you may have on this.

I have tried changing the date options and turning off case sensitivity, hoping the results set would be filtered

Comment: You have to include the wildcards you want. If I wanted all instances where notes contained abc, I would enter `%abc%`.  It's just regular SQL syntax for like.

Comment: @AndrewThank you so much Andrew!